# MapView not showing overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

My task is to show the current location of the user as an overlay on the map.

So far I found that the best way to do it, when GPS is enabled, is like this:

```
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



     // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                Log.d("location", "locationchanged: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());

                List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude(), (int)location.getLongitude());
                OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point, "title", "hello home!");
                Drawable drawable = CouponsMapActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
                HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, CouponsMapActivity.this);   
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
                mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
//              mapView.postInvalidate();
                mapView.invalidate();
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


    }
}
```

I put a debug point in

```
                Log.d("location", "locationchanged: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
```

The location there is correct.

I know that I'm rounding the coordinates and this gives me a somewhat wrong result (it's a quick fix for GeoPoint accepting only int) - but this is not the issue, since the overlay also doesn't appear on the wrong location. It doesn't appear at all.

Edit: Here is HelloItemizedOverlay:

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

private Context mContext;

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      mContext = context;
    }


public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
  return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
  return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}
```

Note: the overlays work when I set the points manually in the main thread like this:

```
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    final HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);  
    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: can you provide the `HelloItemizedOverlay` implmentation? may be the problem is there..

Comment: I noticed that you're not adding `@Override` to your `LocationListerner`'s methods. this may be the problem

Comment: They will override without the annotations. I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: I suggested it because I sometimes had problems just because of the missing annotation...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago and it was somehow related to the drawable bounds. Try using this method when you're setting the drawable parameter on the constructor of HelloItemizedOverlay.

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(boundCenterBottom(drawable), CouponsMapActivity.this);   


private Drawable boundCenterBottom(Drawable marker) {
    marker.setBounds((-marker.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2, -marker.getIntrinsicHeight(),
            marker.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, 0);
    return marker;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the drawable, I edited my post, setting random overlays "manually" works. It's maybe related that onCreate finishes and the map isn't redrawn or something. But I'm calling invalidate()...